# log4j implementation in my spring webapp

Tags: spring, log4j

i need to implement log4j on my spring webapp. I was trying in using log4j.xml and then calling it in my java file private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class);

Somewat like above and then logger.info("Index Controller done successfully");

but it didnt worked out.

So, please get me some steps and where to keep what to make it work. I have kept my log4j.xml inside WEB-INF folder.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Anything contribution from anyone??

Comment: Post your log4j.xml and the full package name of IndexController.

Answer (score 0):

For the default setup, ensure that the log4j.xml file is at the root of the classpath. Also, ensure that you have the log4j (and commons-logging) dependency.

We may need more information to really get this working with your particular setup.